# Scraping Data using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, testing, web-scraping, testcafe, data-extraction

I am working on a project where I want to scrape out data from a website whenever the value of the range slider is changed by the user and compare it with the actual data.

**The tasks are:**

1. Scrape the **actual data**(initial value)
   2.Scrape out the **base data**(the value changed by the user)
2. I am supposed to **extract the base data for each change in value done by the user and compare it with the actual data and store it in local directory**
   (CONDITION: Must be done only using *JavaScript*)

The slider is present within an iframe.

**Can someone please suggest any approach/packages for doing this?**

Comment: Please consider adding some of your code samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to do scraping in javascript:

- Regular Expressions: The hard way
- Cheerio: Core JQuery for traversing the DOM
- JSDOM: The DOM for Node
- Puppeteer: The headless browser
- Nightmare: An alternative to Puppeteer

For more info, try this article:
https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/web-scraping-javascript/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26958831)

Comment: Updated answer @ShaluTD